# SQL CPU Script - count consecutive occurrences of value

Tags: sql-server, cpu-usage

so I'm working on a SQL CPU utilization script that gets the last (for ex, 10 mins of CPU usage), for a SQL instance as available from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers - pretty standard script.

however, what I want to do, is grab this info, but count the consecutive occurrences in the sample (ie 10 mins), so if for 10 mins (10 consecutive records where value > 90%) do *X*

here's the code i'm using: (EDITED FOR CORRECT CODE)

```
DECLARE @ts BIGINT;
DECLARE @lastNmin TINYINT;
SET @lastNmin = 10;
SELECT @ts =(SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM 
sys.dm_os_sys_info); 
SELECT TOP(@lastNmin)
    SQLProcessUtilization AS [SQLServer_CPU_Utilization], 
    SystemIdle AS [System_Idle_Process], 
    100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS 
[Other_Process_CPU_Utilization], 
    DATEADD(ms,-1 *(@ts - [timestamp]),GETDATE())AS [Event_Time] 
FROM (SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]','int')AS record_id, 
    
 record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle) 
 [1]','int')AS [SystemIdle],record.value    
('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization) 
[1]','int')AS     [SQLProcessUtilization], 
[timestamp]      
FROM (SELECT[timestamp], convert(xml, record) AS [record]             
FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers             
WHERE ring_buffer_type =N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'AND record 
LIKE'%%')AS x )AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there's no time-based component to this. Related, you say that you're pulling from `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers` but I don't see a reference to that in your script.

Comment: so sorry - i had the wrong script!! My clipboard tricked me! goin to see if I can edit it thx for your reply.

Comment: Good ol' Tricky Clippy... gets me every time! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a gaps and islands approach. Here's what I came up with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp;

DECLARE @ts BIGINT;
DECLARE @lastNmin TINYINT;
SET @lastNmin = 10;
SELECT @ts =
(
    SELECT cpu_ticks / (cpu_ticks / ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
);
SELECT TOP (@lastNmin)
       SQLProcessUtilization AS [SQLServer_CPU_Utilization],
       SystemIdle AS [System_Idle_Process],
       100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS [Other_Process_CPU_Utilization],
       DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS [Event_Time]

INTO #tmp
FROM
(
    SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id,
           record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS [SystemIdle],
           record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') AS [SQLProcessUtilization],
           [timestamp]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [timestamp],
               CONVERT(XML, record) AS [record]
        FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
        WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
              AND record LIKE '%%'
    ) AS x
) AS y
ORDER BY record_id DESC;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CAST(CASE WHEN [System_Idle_Process] >= 95 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) as [HighCPU]
    FROM #tmp
),
GapsAndIslands AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cte.Event_Time) AS rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte.HighCPU ORDER BY cte.Event_Time) AS rn2
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *, rn1 - rn2 AS GroupID
FROM GapsAndIslands
ORDER BY GapsAndIslands.Event_Time;
```

By way of explanation, I'm creating three synthetic columns

1. a boolean representing the condition you're looking to track (NB - I'm using a different metric than you should because my CPU usage is low!)
2. a row number column across the entire data set
3. a row number column for each distinct value of the tracked metric

What makes this solution work is noting that the difference in those two row number columns will be the same for consecutive rows that have the same value for your tracked metric and will change on the boundaries. I've left that as `GroupID` in the final result set and you can use that to track groups of consecutive rows.

If you instead replace that last select with this:

```
SELECT MIN(Event_Time), MAX(Event_Time)
FROM GapsAndIslands
WHERE [HighCPU] = 1
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(Event_Time);
```

That will give you the time ranges for when the tracked metric was above threshold.

Comment: hello, ben - just circling back on this...thx for the assist - but i want to try to understand what we have.  My intention was to look at the metrics, over the last X mins, and for example ONLY when it is >y AND consecutively y for the last X mins, then do ABC. 

So, to test when I make the threshold (looking at the result set first to make a controlled experiment), =93, out of the 10mins/last 10 records, I get 3 rows for =93 where HIGHCPU=1.  However, this doesn't work, bc the 3 rows are NOT consecutive time occurrences.  Unless I missed something?  still looking at code. plz reply tia

Comment: Unless of course, where the groupid indicates they are consecutive rows where it is the same for every row?  So i need to basically in the end result set IF all rows=groupid(id) then trigger alert. I 'think' I got it now....thx

Comment: @SQLSeeker - right. I'm "showing my work here", GroupID is indeed the identifier for rows that should be considered in the same group with respect to contiguity.